# SSIS package - multiple connection from various envrionment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package (SQL server 2008 r2 version) which connects to the third party database for reading the millions of rows. I have implemented the package in  testing and production environment.

If both these packages run at same time of the day, will there be any issues? This is because
testing and production point to same third party database. They share common user /password. And these are readonly query/work done on the third party database.
Some of the days I am getting error on the testing environment, as 'VS-Broken' connection.

Let us know if I am missing anything here.
Thanks,

Comment: If you are getting a broken connection, then I would say there is a problem.  Either copy the data once and then distribute it internally or stagger the read times.

Comment: Thanks. We need to get the data (import) on daily basis. Later might be on hourly basis too. It is the dynamic data needs to be appended/refreshed.

Comment: There could be an issue to "overloading" the source database when you read twice at the same time.But does your test really need to run the same time as your production?

Comment: personally, I would only pull from PROD and then assuming PROD and TEST can't talk write the read to text files and transfer whenever you need a TEST refresh.